# ibm mobileFirst user authentication with a backend via token

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

i have a backend made with node.js and i need an exemple of ibm MobileFirst authenticationwith ChallengeHandler that sends an email and password and get a token from backend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! it is possible as your requirement first of all go to [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/using-mobilefirst-server-authenticate-external-resources/)

[Getting Familiar with MobileFirst Platform 7.0 OAuth Security](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyeGupYSZj4) Flowing videos  tutorial part 2   MobileFirst Server with  authenticate external resources Node.js .